# When to use virtual or regular users exim/dovecot?

Tags: dovecot, exim, virtualization

I'm setting up an exim/dovecot server but i'm looking into when to use virtual users and when to use regulars. Is there a proper use case?

I guess i just have to use real users because most of them will have ftp access and use the server as a webhost as well. Or maybe it's better to keep email virtual and create real users as well?

Comment: Why a -1? Isn't it a valid question? I did some googling but no one really said why you would use virtual instead of regular ones.

Answer (score 2):

FTP-users also can be virtual and, as far as `dovecot` provide system-wide auth-service, you can use the same virtual accounts for both FTP and IMAP. Sure you have to use FTP-server that allow virtual users.

Answer (score 2):

The reason to use virtual users is quite simple. It allows you to use databases and web front ends to do user authorization, and it is much easier to teach someone how to change a user's password, or create a new user, through a web page, instead of having to give them command line access.

The virtual user model is pretty flexible, you can use it for email, PPPx users, FTP, etc etc..